# Android - Is the Application class instantiated when a BroadcastReceiver is called?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, applicationcontext

is the `Application` class instantiated when a `BroadcastReceiver` is called? I have some logic in the custom Application class which is needed before the logic in `onReceive` of a `BroadcastReceiver` is run. [The documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) says the `Context` argument in the `onReceive` method is the `Context` in which the receiver is running. I was not sure if it is the application in which the receiver is defined(statically in the manifest) or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer this question you can try an expriment. Just extends the Application and log it's class in onReceive() :

```
Log.d(TAG, "Context is " + context.getClass().getName());
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The documentation for Application.onCreate notes:

> Called when the application is starting, before any activity, service,
>   or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created.
>   If onCreate is called before your receiver is, it is by default instantiated first.

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()